# How can I add a link to a pic in my gallery and another slider

Tags: html, css, slider, carousel, bootstrap-modal

Im trying to add a link to the infobig2.jpg image in my gallery section. I would also like to add another slide once you enter the gallery. My website is www.24kdesignz.com in the infographic section I want the pic to link to  http://vs0022.businesscatalyst.com/

```
<img class="img-responsive project-image" src="assets/images/info.jpg" alt=""><!--Project thumb -->

<div class="hover-mask">
<h2 class="project-title">Infographic</h2><!--Project Title -->
<p>Illustrated | Icon Driven</p><!--Project Subtitle -->
</div>

<!--==== Project Preview HTML ====-->

<div class="sr-only project-description" data-images="assets/images/infobig.jpg,assets/images/infobig2.jpg" >

<p>Infographics – An Infographic is a visual representation of data and  information that is presented through a series of design-centric graphics. Its sole purpose is to educate viewers on a topic in a simplistic way – with information that is easy to digest.</p>

</div>
</article><!--End Project Item -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After inspecting your site it looks like you have a lot of plugins. The portfolio project section from your site's theme is injected using a jQuery library called "Masonry." Inside of your projects assets >> javascript folder there's also a file called "scripts.js" - this is where the theme author injects the images into the portfolio project items.

Solution: Images can't be links. You have to wrap it in an anchor tag. In your specific case, you're going to have to do it using jQuery.

Assuming your HTML markup looks something like this, add a unique id selector to the image you want to become a link:

```
<li id ="image2">
  <img id ="uniqueId" src="/assets/images/infobig2.png">
</li>
```

Then use jQuery to grab it and wrap it in an anchor tag:

```
$("#uniqueId").wrap($('<a>', {
  href: '/assets/png/' + data.uniqueId
}));
```

The other solution here would be to just add a link under the image using plain html if you don't feel comfortable editing your theme's jQuery code.

Comment: thanks! much appreciated, i think i will just add link under the image